# Задача на сортировку и последовательность. Сортировка масс

Tags: c++, сортировка, олимпиада

Условин задачи : [условие и тестирующая система](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=252) Как известно, Россия является одним из ведущих экспортеров нефти. Разные страны мира, от достаточно больших до сравнительно маленьких, нуждаются в этой нефти как в воздухе. В ее состав в больших количествах входят ароматические углеводороды, которые обуславливают ее высокое качество. Доставка нефти в пункт назначения осуществляется с помощью нефтепровода. Считается, что количество нефти, отправленное в страну назначения, равно количеству полученной нефти. На самом деле это, конечно, не так. Как и многое другое, нефть воруют некоторые несознательные личности. Причем неофициально считается, что больше нефти воруют в нефтепроводах тех стран, куда нефти посылается больше (может быть, несознательные личности считают, что приносят, таким образом, меньше ущерба, кто знает...). Официальное руководство компании «Русская Нефть» решило узнать, правдивый это слух или нет, чтобы усилить (а может просто установить) охрану на тех нефтепроводах, где больше всего воруют нефть.

Для этого им нужно отсортировать нефтепроводы по количеству нефти, которая протекает в направлении какой-то страны за сутки. У компании «Русская Нефть», как и у любой уважающей себя компании, есть несколько штатных программистов, и руководство предложило им решить эту, в сущности, нетрудную задачу. Но программистов поставило в тупик то, что данные о количестве нефти представлены в разных единицах измерения (начиная от граммов и заканчивая тоннами).

Поэтому они решили найти человека, который был бы в силах решить эту задачу за них, и обещают взять его на работу в эту перспективную и процветающую компанию. Решите задачу, и, кто знает, может, повезет именно Вам?

Входные данные

В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT находится целое число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000) — количество нефтепроводов. В каждой из следующих N строк находится количество (точнее — масса) нефти, транспортированной по соответствующему нефтепроводу за сутки, по одному в строке. Масса нефти задана целым числом от 1 до 10000 с указанием соответствующей единицы измерения. Число и единица измерения разделены ровно одним пробелом. Единица измерения задается одной из трех букв: g (граммы), p (пуды), t (тонны), причем перед этой буквой может стоять одна из приставок: m (милли-), k (кило-), M (мега-), G (гига-). Напомним, что эти приставки обозначают умножение единицы измерения на 10–3, 103, 106 и 109 соответственно. 1 пуд = 16380 граммов, 1 тонна = 106 граммов.

Выходные данные

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите N строк, в которых должны быть записаны массы нефти в порядке неубывания. Каждая строка должна описывать массу нефти в одном из нефтепроводов. Массы должны быть описаны в том же формате, в котором записаны во входном файле. Приоритет равных масс, записанных в разных форматах должен соответствовать порядку, в котором они следуют во входном файле.

[image: Пример]

Написал свой код, валит 17 тест, можете помочь обнаружить и ликвидировать ошибку, пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

  int n = 0, mini = 0;

  string s;

  cin >> n;

  vector<string> l(n);

  vector<long long> a(n);

  vector<double> m(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> a[i];
    cin >> l[i];
    if(l[i].size() == 1) {
      if(l[i][0] == 'g') m[i] = 1;
      else if(l[i][0] == 'p') m[i] = 16380;
      else m[i] = 1000000;
    } else {
      if(l[i][1] == 'g') m[i] = 1;
      else if(l[i][1] == 'p') m[i] = 16380;
      else m[i] = 1000000;
      if(l[i][0] == 'm') m[i] *= 0.001;
      else if(l[i][0] == 'k') m[i] *= 1000;
      else if(l[i][0] == 'M') m[i] *= 1000000;
      else m[i] *= 1000000000;
    }
    m[i] *= 1000;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mini = i;
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if(double(a[j] * m[j]) < double(a[mini] * m[mini]))
        mini = j;
    }
    swap(a[i], a[mini]);
    swap(l[i], l[mini]);
    swap(m[i], m[mini]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << a[i] << ' ' << l[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Есть такая программа](https://linux.die.net/man/1/units) (возможно будет интересным поискать ее сорсы)

Comment: Вы используете неустойчивую сортировку выбором, а для решения требуется [устойчивая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), например та, что реализована в [стандартной библиотеке](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/). Значения `1 Mg`, `1 t`, `1 g`, должны быть в следующем порядке `1 g`, `1 Mg`, `1 t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна применить устойчивую сортировку. Например, так:

```
long long coeff(const string& u) {
    char p, v;

    if (strchr("gpt", u[0])) {
        v = u[0];
        p = ' ';
        }
    else {
        p = u[0];
        v = u[1];
        }

    long long r = 1;

    switch (v) {
        case 'g':
            r = 1000ll;
            break;

        case 'p':
            r = 16380000ll;
            break;

        case 't':
            r = 1000000000ll;
            break;
        }

    switch (p) {
        case 'm':
            r /= 1000;
            break;

        case 'k':
            r *= 1000;
            break;

        case 'M':
            r *= 1000000;
            break;

        case 'G':
            r *= 1000000000;
            break;
        }

    return r;
    }

int main() {
    int N;
    vector<pair<double, string>> v;
    cin >> N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        long long val;
        string unit;
        cin >> val >> unit;
        v.push_back(make_pair(double(val)*coeff(unit),
                              to_string(val) + " " + unit));
        }

    stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto t : v)
        cout << t.second << endl;
    }
```

Я тут пару использую, просто чтобы не возиться с восстановлением строки из `double`.

Можно и обычную сортировку, добавив поле номера считанной строки - я взял `tuple`:

```
using namespace std;

long long coeff(const string& u) {
    char p, v;

    if (strchr("gpt", u[0])) {
        v = u[0];
        p = ' ';
        }
    else {
        p = u[0];
        v = u[1];
        }

    long long r = 1;

    switch (v) {
        case 'g':
            r = 1000ll;
            break;

        case 'p':
            r = 16380000ll;
            break;

        case 't':
            r = 1000000000ll;
            break;
        }

    switch (p) {
        case 'm':
            r /= 1000;
            break;

        case 'k':
            r *= 1000;
            break;

        case 'M':
            r *= 1000000;
            break;

        case 'G':
            r *= 1000000000;
            break;
        }

    return r;
    }

int main() {
    int N;
    vector<tuple<double, int, long long, string>> v;
    cin >> N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        long long val;
        string unit;
        cin >> val >> unit;
        v.push_back(make_tuple(double(val)*coeff(unit), i, val, unit));
        }

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto t : v)
        cout << get<2>(t) << " " << get<3>(t) << endl;
    }
```

ЗЫ. Дожились, политику в задачи суют... Скоро будем считать, сколько надо убить украинцев, чтобы освободить ДНР...

Comment: Решение с tuple верное, спасибо!)